# safari getSelection() not working

Tags: javascript, safari, textselection

I've been puzzled as to why this behaviour happens on safari. I'm trying to get selection when i type some text and for that i use the window.getSelection() and it works perfectly fine on Firefox, Chrome, Opera and so on giving me something like:

```
Selection {}
anchorNode: text
anchorOffset: 14
baseNode: text
baseOffset: 14
extentNode: text
extentOffset: 14
focusNode: text
focusOffset: 14
isCollapsed: true
rangeCount: 1
type: "Caret"
__proto__: Selection
```

However on safari9 when i do the exact same thing, the result will be this:

```
Selection
anchorNode: null
anchorOffset: 0
baseNode: null
baseOffset: 0
extentNode: null
extentOffset: 0
focusNode: null
focusOffset: 0
isCollapsed: true
rangeCount: 0
type: "None"
__proto__: SelectionPrototype
```

I am wondering if this is something i'm doing wrong? If it's indeed a bug or it's not working is there a possible workaround? Or another method to obtain the same information that will work on most browsers?

Answer (score 3):

I'm running into a similar issue when I'm dealing with a contenteditable div and seems safari defaults `user select` to `none` which makes it so that user cant select anything. I did

```
[contenteditable] {
  -webkit-user-select: auto;
  user-select: all;
}
```

You can try replace `[contenteditble]` to `input` or other css elements.

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE**

I found a clean solution :
Look at this : https://github.com/megahertz/jquery.get-word-by-event

it uses the click EVENT object (cleaner than window.getSelection I think):

```
var range = document.caretRangeFromPoint(event.clientX, event.clientY);
```

And it works great on iOS 12.

**OLD POST**

I had the same issue on iOS12 only 
(no mater -webkit-user-select)

I manage to get it work again by adding : contentEditable="true" 
to the Div container,

BUT (big BUT) unfortunately keyboard appears and content becomes editable !!
(which is pretty much expected...)

I'm still looking for a workaround 
@galart Did you find something ?